# Связь 1С и интеренет магазина

Tags: 1с

Здравствуйте, пробую настроить подключение между 1С 8.3.9 предприятие с конфигурацией управление торговлей 11.2 (пустая учебная конфигурация) и ocStore 2.1.0.1 с модулем Обмен данными с 1C v8.x. Застопорился уже на этапе создания узла обмена в 1С. В поле адреса ввожу домен и путь к файлу exchang.php.так же ввожу логин и пароль (не могу понять - это пароль и логин, который указывали при доступе в админ панель или тот, который прописывали в самом модуле обмена). Когда пробую протестировать соединение У меня выскакивает ошибка, что не удалось установить соединение. Произошла ошибка.Не удалось получить данные с сервера. Проверьте правильность адреса сервера, порта, имя пользователя, пароля, а так же настройки подключения к интернету. Авторизация не выполнена. Проверьте имя пользователя и пароль. Как для начала, хотя бы настроить соединение. С 1С знаком поверхностно. В какую сторону следует копать и где можно просматривать ошибки подключений в 1С.

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов решения может быть множество. Но мне помогли следующие:

1. Добавить строку авторизации в .htaccess

   ```
   RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
   ```
2. Проверить в файле обмена в директории export в начале кода наличие строк:

   ```
   $remote_user = $_SERVER["REMOTE_USER"]
   ? $_SERVER["REMOTE_USER"] : $_SERVER["REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER"];
   $strTmp = base64_decode(substr($remote_user,6));
   if ($strTmp)
   list($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) = explode(':', $strTmp);
   ```